# Recuperar ultimo id inserido e curso selecionado

Tags: c#, sql-server

Eu tenho a seguinte situação:

Em um mesmo formulário, eu insiro um aluno:

```
        SqlCommand inserirAluno = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALUNOS (Nome, DataNascimento, CPF, Endereco, Bairro, " +
             "CEP, Cidade, IdEstado, Sexo) " +
             "Values(@Nome, @DataNascimento, @CPF, @Endereco, @Bairro, @CEP, @Cidade, @IdEstado, @Sexo)", sqlConn);
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@DataNascimento", SqlDbType.Date).Value = mtb_Nasc.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Nome.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@CPF", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = mtb_Cpf.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Endereco", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Endereco.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Bairro", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Bairro.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@CEP", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = mtb_Cep.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Cidade", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Cidade.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@IdEstado", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cb_Uf.SelectedIndex;
        if (rb_Masc.Checked)
        {
            inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Sexo", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Sexo", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
        }
```

E insiro também uma matricula deste aluno:

```
        SqlCommand inserirMatricula = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MATRICULAS(IdAluno, IdCurso, Periodo, Mensalidade, " +
            "FlagAtivo, DataMatricula)" +
            "Values(@IdAluno, @IdCurso, @Periodo, @Mensalidade, @FlagAtivo, @DataMatricula)");
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@IdAluno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@IdCurso", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@Periodo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tb_Semestre.Text;
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@Mensalidade", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = tb_Mensalidade.Text;
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@FlagAtivo", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@DataMatricula", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

Porém, na inserção da matricula, eu preciso recuperar o ultimo id do aluno inserido (desse mesmo formulário) e o id do curso que selecionei na combobox. Como faço isso?

Comment: Se a coluna do id do aluno for do tipo identiy, podes fazer esta query: select @@Indentity e recuperas o último valor gerado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso, você precisa usar a função `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` e o método `command.ExecuteScalar()`.

```
try
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

    SqlCommand inserirAluno = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALUNOS (Nome, DataNascimento, CPF, Endereco, Bairro, " +
                 "CEP, Cidade, IdEstado, Sexo) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID " +
                 "Values(@Nome, @DataNascimento, @CPF, @Endereco, @Bairro, @CEP, @Cidade, @IdEstado, @Sexo)", sqlConn);

    inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@DataNascimento", SqlDbType.Date).Value = mtb_Nasc.Text;
    inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Nome.Text;
    inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@CPF", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = mtb_Cpf.Text;
    inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Endereco", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Endereco.Text;
    inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Bairro", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Bairro.Text;
    inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@CEP", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = mtb_Cep.Text;
    inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Cidade", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Cidade.Text;
    inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@IdEstado", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cb_Uf.SelectedIndex;

    if (rb_Masc.Checked)
    {
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Sexo", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Sexo", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
    }

    sqlConn.Open();
    int id = (int)inserirAluno.ExecuteScalar();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Tratar exceção
}
finally
{
    if (sqlConn.State != sqlConn.Closed)
    {
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Perceba que modifiquei seu código e adicionei logo após o `INSERT` a função `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` que irá informar ao `SQL Server` para retornar o ID do registro inserido.

Além disso, no final do seu código adicionei `int id = (int)inserirAluno.ExecuteScalar();` que por sua vez será responsável por executar o comando `SQL` e retornar o `ID` inserido que informamos anteriormente.

Dessa forma, na variável `id` você terá o `ID` do aluno inserido.

Comment: No caso, ao inserir o ExecuteScalar, o Visual Studio me retorna uma exceção exigindo que tenha uma conexão com o banco aberta. Porém, a conexão só é aberta no bloco try-catch. Devo abrir a conexão na passagem do comando de dos parâmetros?

Comment: Sim, exatamente. O bloco try catch deve abranger todo o seu comando SQL desde a abertura da conexão até o fechamento da mesma. Vou atualizar a resposta.